# Mapping the Riemann sphere with unit interval deleted to the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

Let [0, 1] ⊂ C stand for the closed interval between 0 and 1, and Ω =
C \ [0, 1] ∪ {∞} a subset of the Riemann sphere. Find a biholomorphic map of Ω on the unit disc.

The Riemann sphere with the real unit interval deleted is not simply connected, so I don't see how there can be such a mapping, but if someone could give me a hint it would be much appreciated.

Comment: The Riemann sphere without the unit interval deleted **is** simply connected (in the same way as the punctured sphere is simply connected).

Comment: Do you need an explicit map or is it sufficient to prove existence?

Comment: either would help, but I'm looking for a specific map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The existence of such a mapping follows immediately from the Riemann mapping theorem, since it basically says that any simply connected subset of the Riemann sphere which does not contain at least two points of the sphere is biholomorphically equivalent to the unit disk.

I will construct such a mapping in three steps:
Firstly, $f(z) = 1/z$ maps $\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\} \setminus [0, 1]$ to $\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\} \setminus [1, \infty] = \mathbb{C} \setminus [1, \infty)$. 
Secondly, $g(z) = \sqrt{z - 1}$ maps $\mathbb{C} \setminus [1, \infty)$ to the upper half plane $\{z \in \mathbb{C} | \operatorname{Im} z > 0\}$.
Finally, $h(z) = \frac{z-i}{z + i}$, the [Cayley transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform), maps the upper half plane to the unit disk.

$f, g, h$ are biholomorphic on their respective domains, so $h \circ g \circ f$ does the job. Explicitly, $(h \circ g \circ f)(z) = \frac{\sqrt{1/z - 1} - i}{\sqrt{1/z - 1} + i} = \left(\sqrt{1 - z} - i \sqrt{z} \right)^2$.